# Is there any normed space which does satisfies paralleogram law but not a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Parallelogram law is a necessary condition for a Banach space to be Hilbert, but it is not sufficient.
Can anyone give an example of that kind of normed space, which satisfies
$$
\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\big(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\big)
$$
but is not an Hilbert space?

Comment: Take any incomplete inner product space (so necessarily infinite-dimensional), for example $C([0,1])$ with the usual integral inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$ (and the corresponding induced norm $\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$).

Comment: None of the proofs require completeness of the vactor space (or at least they shouldn't) so the norm satisfying the parallelogram law is equivalent to having an inner product space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\text{paralellogram law}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \text{inner product space}
\\
\text{Hilbert space}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \text{inner product space and complete}
$$

so the answer would be: an inner product space which is not compete.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105198/a-banach-space-that-satisfies-parallelogram-law-is-a-hilbert-space), you will see that for a complete normed space it is actually sufficient using [Polarization identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). Therefore, the only way to find your sort of example is by finding a non complete normed space, which should also be an innner product space.